# Foundation Orbit - Full Page Width

Tags: zurb-foundation

Is it possible to make the orbiter (foundation 5) feature full width, ignoring the page margins?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by setting the `margin` and `padding` of your `.row` and `.columns` to 0. Along with a `min-width:100%` for your `.row`.

Here's the full CSS:

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.row {
    min-width:100%;
    padding:0 !important;
}

.columns {
    padding:0 !important;
}
```

Here's a working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/3ALbW/)**.

Comment: This would destroy all other rows and mess with a lot of groundwork by Foundation